# EJB Scheduler doesn't run every hour?

Tags: java, ejb, scheduler

I have an EJB Scheduler. I want that the Method runs every hour. But the Method only runs one Time. I don't know why.

This is my EJB Class:

```
@Singleton
public class DBTimeout {

  @PersistenceContext
  private EntityManager em;

  @Inject
  private Logger logger;

  @Schedule(second = "0", minute = "0", hour = "*/1", info = "Every 1 hour", persistent = false)
  public void refreshDBConnectionPool() {
    em.createNativeQuery("SELECT 1");
    logger.info("successfully executed cronejob for refreshing Database Connection Pool.");
  }

}
```

Comment: Have you tried just setting the hour to "*"?  To me it seems like the same thing but I'm not sure what else I'd try.

Comment: If i use * the method would be execute every time or not ?

Comment: It should mean all hours.  You've got the minute and second set so every hour on the hour it should run.

Comment: Ok thanks, i will test it. But what if i want that the method execute every 4 hours. I have donr (minute="0";second="0";hour="*/4"). But it doesnt work. Why ?

Comment: What application server are you using?  The syntax you originally showed should work.  I've used Wildfly 8 through 10 with very similar syntax and never had a problem.  Before you waste 4 hours testing, maybe you should make sure you can, for example, run something every 4 minutes or something.

Comment: Ok. I'm going to test it now. I use wildfly 9.0.2

Comment: Maybe `em.createNativeQuery("SELECT 1");` throws the 2nd time and you don't see the log? Or it deadlocks. Or your server restarts / dies on the full hour?

Answer (score 0):

With Wildfly, make sure you're using standalone-full.xml as your configuration.  The default standalone.xml does not have support for EJB schedules.

Comment: Yes i use standalone-full.xml

Comment: I have another ejb scheduler in another class which i call on a fix time. It works without problems. But the syntax every 4 hours i don't know why it not function

Answer (score 0):

hey can you try code from bellow?

```
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.ejb.ScheduleExpression;
import javax.ejb.Singleton;
import javax.ejb.Startup;
import javax.ejb.Timeout;
import javax.ejb.TimerService;

@Singleton
@Startup
public class DBTimeout {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    @Inject
    private Logger logger;

    @Resource
    private TimerService timerService;

    @Timeout
    public void timeOut() {
        refreshDBConnectionPool();
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void initTimer() {
        System.out.println("INIT-CALLED");
        ScheduleExpression exp = new ScheduleExpression();
        exp.hour("*/1").minute("*");
        timerService.createCalendarTimer(exp);
    }

    public void refreshDBConnectionPool() {
        em.createNativeQuery("SELECT 1");
        logger.info("successfully executed cronejob for refreshing Database Connection Pool.");
   }
}
```